# About string input in C

Tags: c, string

I am a beginner in programming and I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char x[] = "",
        y[] = "",
        z[] = "";

   printf("Enter a string: ");
   scanf("%s", x);

   printf("Enter another string: ");
   scanf("%s", y);

   printf("Enter one more string: ");
   scanf("%s", z);

   printf("\n");
   printf("x is %s\n", x);
   printf("y is %s\n", y);
   printf("z is %s\n", z);

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

When I enter "I" for x, "am" for y and "happy" for z, the result is like that:

```
x is ppy
y is appy
z is happy
```

Does anybody know what is the problem? Thanks you!

Answer (score 7):

```
char x[] = "";
```

is equivalent to:

```
char x[1] = {'\0'};
```

As you see, `x` has only one element for the null terminator, not enough space to store any non-empty string. The same for `y` and `z`.

To fix it, define `x`, `y`, `z` with enough space, and it's better to use `fgets` instead of `scanf` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("x is %s\n", x);
printf("y is %s\n", y);
printf("z is %s\n", z);

Replace these lines with :
printf("x is %s address of x: %u\n", x,x);
printf("y is %s address of y: %u\n", y,y);
printf("z is %s address of z: %u\n", z,z);

By doing so you will find:
Enter a string: i 
Enter another string: am
Enter one more string: happy

x is ppy    address of x: 1572060267
y is apply  address of y: 1572060266
z is happy  address of z: 1572060265

65 66 67 68 69 70
      i  \0
      a  m \0
h  a  p  p  y  \0

Third time when you enter 'happy' the memory location gets updated as above, since 'x' address is 67 so it starts printing from 67 unto NULL character i.e. \0.
In the same way 'y' and 'z'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be giving segmentation fault.

**Reason :**

Since x, y, z are arrays with zero characters (but remember, '\0' will be present, so effectively 1 byte space available for x[], y[] and z[]), when you input "i", 2 characters will be effectively copied to address location pointed by x, i.e 'i' and '\0'. This itself will result in a seg fault while printing. Same thing applicable for y[] and z[].

Now, leaving the seg fault aside and answering your question:

```
char x[] = "";
char y[] = "";
char z[] = "";
```

Typically, the address locations for these variables when executed will be like this.
Let x[] will cover the memory location 763 (remember, x[], y[], z[] has only 1 byte).
Stack grows such a way that y[] will cover location 762 and z[] will cover location 761.

Now, as Anita Agrawal mentioned, this is what happens when you give your inputs to the program

```
760 761 762 763 764 765 766 767
            i   \0                
        a   m   \0                
    h   a   p   p   y   \0
```

"happy" overwrites "am" that had overwritten "i".

Therefore,

```
1. printing x will start printing characters from location 763 till '\0' => ppy
2. printing y will start printing characters from location 762 till '\0' => appy
3. printing z will start printing characters from location 761 till '\0' => happy
```